# What Do Hilbert Spaces Look Like?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

For any vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, let $X$ be a set whose cardinality is the dimension of $V$.  Then $V \cong \bigoplus\limits_{i \in X} \mathbb{C}$ as vector spaces.

Is there a similar description of arbitrary Hilbert spaces?  Is there something they all "look" like?

Comment: Note that your description of vector spaces leans heavily on Zorn's lemma (or equivalently, the axiom of choice).

Comment: Perhaps there is some nice description of inner products; perhaps every inner product can be represented as an integral over some indexing set.  This is certainly the case for some of the more commonly used inner products.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that a description as a direct sum over an infinite index set gives a lot of information about what the vector space "looks like"... The topology of these spaces becomes very unintuitive, at least IMO. (And from my point of view all these spaces are contractible anyway :) )

Comment: "Looks like" ... Of course I guess that is subjective.   To me, $\mathbb R$ does not "look like" a giant direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ for some set $\Gamma$. This follows directly from [Parseval's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity).

Comment: What's the inner product in $\ell^2(\Gamma)$ when $\Gamma$ is uncountable?

Comment: Every element in $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ has countable support so it is just $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma} x_\gamma \overline{y}_\gamma$. This is really a countable sum as you may always chop it down to the supports of $x$ and $y$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, you can apply the same thing as you did with a generic vectors space and obtain that $$H \cong \bigoplus\limits_{i \in X} \mathbb{C}.$$
Notes that this relies on the notion of Hamel dimension of the space of a vector space.

However, you can say that a Hilbert space has its Hilbert dimension equal to the cardinality of a certain set $E$, then
$$H\cong \ell_2 (E)$$(i.e. a set of square-summable sequences indexed by elementss of $E$), so, for example, all separable Hilbert spaces are "all the same". Note that the Hilbert dimension is rarely the same as Hamel dimension.

Comment: What is the inner product on $\ell_2(E)$ when $E$ is uncountable?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom naturally, $(x,y)_{\ell_2(E)} = \sum_{e\in E}x_e\bar y_e$. The elements of $\ell_2(E)$ have at most countable number of non-zero elements ("of countable support"), hence this sum is merely a sum over a countable set of indexes (intersection of supports of $x$ and $y$).

Answer (score 0):

Every Hilbert space is isomorphic to $L^2(X)$ for some measure space $X$. This is a generalization of Tomek's answer.

Now this is redundant, since $X$ is not determined up to isomorphism by $H$. However, this formulation sheds light onto the spectral theorem:

If $A$ is a self-adjoint (possibly unbounded) operator $H \rightarrow H$, then there is a measure space $X$ and an isomorphism $\phi:H \rightarrow L^2(X)$ such that $\phi A \phi^{-1}:L^2(X) \rightarrow L^2(X)$ is multiplication by a measurable real-valued function.

(You might need $H$ separable for this theorem)